# How to set up MS Exchange Autodiscover alongside Wordpress

Tags: htaccess, email, domain, hosting, microsoft

My client's IT person has thrown up a flag regarding their need to use [MS Exchange Autodiscover service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/autodiscover?view=exchserver-2019), and that potential issues may possibly arise (ie as a result of sharing the domain with the WordPress website).

From my reading and discussions with the client's IT person, it *should* work without needing any additional steps - but may result in unwanted request handling (ie by WordPress), and even sever errors if just left for WordPress to figure out.

Ideally I don't WP "touching" these requests (want to keep things as separate as possible).

The default URL Autodiscover looks for is:

https://www.example.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

I am thinking that maybe creating a special rule for in the `.htaccess` file to keep that particular URL from being processed by WP or the other `.htaccess` rules?

If this is the best way to go, perhaps someone could show me an example of this?

Or if there are other preferred ways to have these two coexist?

Comment: I thought autodiscover [used separate DNS entries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/architecture/client-access/autodiscover?view=exchserver-2019#autodiscover-in-dns)? So you really want to set something up to serve the XML on autodiscover.example.com, not www.example.com. (Although yes, it looks like it will try example.com/autodiscover - not www.example.com/autodiscover - first.)

Comment: The default WordPress htaccess configuration will serve anything that exists on disk without processing it by WP, which is how the files in wp-content/uploads work. So if you have autodiscover/autodiscover.xml on disk then the web server will serve it without going through WP code. You can even set up a `<Location /autodiscover>` with a separate document root so that the files don't need to be in the WordPress file tree either.